# Как проверить текст на наличие букв?

Tags: jquery, text

Нужно проверить некий текст на наличие букв. То есть я хочу создать функцию, которая будет получать текст, искать в нём буквы и, если найдет - запускать первую функцию, если же нет - то вторую.

Вся беда в том, что я не знаю, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример текста без букв, жутко интересно на это посмотреть.

Comment: Просто скажу что там одни цыфры

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение (`i` для игнорирования регистра):

```
if (/[a-zа-яё]/i.test(inputText)){
    containsLetters(inputText);
} else {
    doesNotContainLetters(inputText);
}
```

**P.S.** Проверяет только на наличие латинских букв или букв русского языка.

Answer (score 2):

Если аргумент isNaN – не число, то он автоматически преобразуется к числу, если не получается, то строка с символами. 
Работает со всеми символами

```js
alert(isNaN(prompt("Введите строку", "строка")));
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/number

Comment: `:` - вроде как не буква

Comment: На некоторые символы можно отдельно поверку сделать, это не так страшно

Comment: В тексте есть цыфры и пробелы. Так что ваш вариант отпадает.

Comment: Но ведь нужно только наличие проверить? Это ведь не значит, что он должен состоять только из букв. Формулируйте вопрос конкретнее

Comment: "445 буква 445 буква" к примеру сработает

Comment: На `0xf` — выдает false. На `1e1` — тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Если число то искать по id, если стринг то другое выражение:

```
const searchIdTerm = term && !isNaN(term) ? `id = ${term}` : '';
```